# How can i split a string into words without split function in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I split string into words without using split function in javascript. I wonder for a little help.
this is my code:

```
function trocearCadena(cadena) {
var posEspacios = buscarEspacios(cadena);
var palabras = [];
var j = 0;
while (true) {
    var pos = posEspacios.shift();
    var subcad = (j == 0) ? cadena.substring(0, pos) : cadena.substring(j + 1, pos);
    palabras.push(subcad);
    j += pos;
    if (j > cadena.length) {
        var ultpal = cadena.substring(pos + 1);
        palabras.push(ultpal);
        break;
    }
}
return palabras;
```

}

```
 function buscarEspacios(cadena) {
    var espacios = [];
    var pos = -1;
    do{
      pos = cadena.indexOf(" ", ++pos);
       if (pos != -1) espacios.push(pos);
    } while (pos != -1);
    return espacios;
 }
```

Comment: `cadena.match(/\S+/g);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your variable names mean, so I wasn't able to fix the code. Here's another one:

```js
str = "How can I split string into     words without using split function in javascript."

var words = [""];

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
  if(str[i] !== " ")
    words[words.length - 1] += str[i];
  else if(words[words.length - 1])
    words.push("");

document.write(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you also can't use what @Oriol suggested, I would use a recursive function like in the following example:

```
function _split(s, arr) {
  var 
    str = s.trim(),
    words = arr || [],
    i = str.indexOf(' ');

  if(i !== -1) {
    words.push(str.substr(0, i)); // collect the next word
    return _split(str.slice(i + 1), words); // recur with new string and words array to keep collecting
  } else {
    words.push(str); // collect the last word
    return words;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
_split('  one two    three   ');
//=> ["one", "two", "three"]
```